# How to get Bundle Object from ClassLoader? (Java, OSGI)

Tags: java, oop, osgi, bundle, classloader

I'm working on some old code which depends on:

```
import org.eclipse.osgi.framework.adaptor.BundleClassLoader;
```

and uses it here:

```
protected Bundle getBundle() {
    BundleClassLoader cl = (BundleClassLoader) editor.getClass().getClassLoader();
    return cl.getBundle();
}
```

Is there a new way to do this? (Retrieve the bundle from the ClassLoader) I'm not finding any resources on this change. BundleClassLoader seems to have been deprecated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FrameworkUtil.

```
 Bundle b = FrameworkUtil.getBundle( editor.getClass() );
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thanks Peter!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `editor.getClass()`? Also beware with this method... it can return null, for example if the class was loaded by a non-OSGi classloader like the bootstrap loader.

Comment: Edited for the class instead of instance

Comment: Yeah, I had to add getClass() but I figured that it wasn't a big discrepancy to warrant a change but I suppose being thorough is valuable! Thanks again.